# Access mac server from iphone using hostname?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, hostname

I'm running a websever on my macbook and I want to access it from my phone over wifi using my home network. If I type in the IP address, it connects just fine, but I need the domain name to be fully-qualified in order for me to get anywhere within the web app. How do I set my host name on my home network so I can access the server with a fully-qualified name?

PS (I can't root the phone so I can't edit its host files or redirect its DNS).

Comment: Sounds like you need to build yourself a DNS server. :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple version is machine name dot local.  Example: macbookpro.local  Of course I'm running a DNS server on my home network (MacMini Server) so it works.  You may need to do the same thing.  I think the server download for OsX is $20, and adds DNS functionality (along with LOTS of other cool stuff).

Comment: How do I redirect the phone to the local network's DNS instead of whichever it's pointing to?

Comment: By having your own DNS server configured (like I mention I do) and having your iPhone use it instead.  Just get into your home router and change the IP address of the DNS server that you use to match the IP address of your home computer (after you set up the DNS server on it).  Use your current DNS IP address as the second one listed.  Then if your DNS server doesn't have a record, you'll try the second.  If it does have it (it knows about itself) it'll respond.

Comment: This is basically the only way to do what you are trying to do.  There HAS to be a DNS server involved, that has a domain record, and is pointing at your server.